# Postgres aggregate problem

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm not sure why this won't work:

```
SELECT u.id, u.tag, u.unit_type, Count(p.id) AS num_points
FROM ot2.unit u
INNER JOIN ot2.point p on p.unit_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING Count(p.id) > 800;
```

> ERROR: column "u.tag" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   SQL state: 42803

I have already provided a column for group by.

Comment: This won't work in all RDBMSs [except MySQL](http://mysql.lamphost.net/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html). The error message tells you all you need to know! It doesn't ask for "a column". It tells you the exact additional one you need. You will also need to sort out `u.unit_type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just what the error says. u.tag is not in the group by and you aren't telling how to aggregate the different u.tag values to a single one.

More concrete you have 2 options:

- Add u.tag in the group by clause (and u.unit_type as well)
- use an aggregate function on those 2 fields (min, max, sum, avg, ....)

Comment: Why? This explains nothing past a restatement of the error message.

Comment: By definition: if you have a group by statement every field in the select list either has to be named in the group by statement or has to have a aggregate function. In this case u.id is in the group by and (p.id) has an aggregate function count(). u.tag and u.unit_type are in neither.